# $O_k=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$, whenever $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ and $d\neq 1$ mod $4$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I'm going through a proof in my lecture notes for the mentioned statement. Showing $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]\subseteq O_K$ was easy to understand, but then there's a few gaps when showing that $O_K\subseteq\mathbb{Z[\sqrt{d}]}$.

Let $\alpha = a+b\sqrt{d}\in O_K$(we know that $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$). When $b=0$, we have $a\in O_K\cap\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Z}$. So far so good. When, $b\neq 0$, the min poly of $\alpha$ is $f_{\alpha}(X)=X^2-2aX+(a^2-b^2d)$. As $\alpha\in O_K$, we know $f_{\alpha}\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$, so $2a, (a^2-b^2d)\in\mathbb{Z}$. But then the proof says that this implies that $4db^2\in \mathbb{Z}$. The rest of the proof is straightforward, but I don't understand why $4db^2$ must be an integer.

Comment: It's the discriminant $\, B^2-4AC = B^2-4C\,$ of your monic quadratic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$ 4db^2 = (\,\underbrace{2a}_{\in\mathbb Z}\,)^2-4\cdot(\,\underbrace{a^2-b^2d}_{\in\mathbb Z}\,)\in\mathbb Z$$

Comment: ah perfect, I tried playing round with the two numbers, but just couldn't get $4db^2$